# Accesing variables from nested functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, nested-function

I want to access the variable value from a callback outside the function

```
function test()
{
    var videoData=[];
    searchYTVideos("test1",0,function(vidYT){
       //concat to videoData
       videoData = videoData.concat(vidYT);

    });

    searchVideo("test2",0,function(vidDM){
        //concat to videoData
        videoData = videoData.concat(vidDM);
    });
    console.log(videoData);
}
```

But, I get a blank value. How can I concat the value of vidYT and vidDM to videoData

Comment: Can you share the code for `searchYTVideos` and `searchVideo`? Maybe they're treating the functions they are receiving as callbacks that aren't executed right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is asynchronous so `console.log` is executing before the callbacks have been called.

You can try nesting your callbacks:

```
var videoData=[];
searchYTVideos("test1", 0, function(vidYT) {
    //concat to videoData
    videoData = videoData.concat(vidYT);

    searchVideo("test2", 0, function(vidDM){
        //concat to videoData
        videoData = videoData.concat(vidDM);

        console.log(videoData);
    });
});
```

Or if you don't want to nest them, you can use flags/counter and a third function that checks to see if the callbacks have been called:

```
var videoData=[];
var numCalled = 0;

searchYTVideos("test1",0,function(vidYT){
   //concat to videoData
   videoData = videoData.concat(vidYT);

   numCalled++;
   logData();

});

searchVideo("test2",0,function(vidDM){
    //concat to videoData
    videoData = videoData.concat(vidDM);
    numCalled++;
    logData();
});

function logData() {
    if(numCalled === 2) {
        console.log(videoData);
    }
}
```

Personally, I think the nested version is easier to understand.

Comment: I agree, simply used the nested version and its working

Answer (score 0):

When the browser hits the `console.log`, assuming both search functions are async, then `videoData` might still be empty because the callbacks haven't executed yet.

> Welcome to the async wonders of JS!

Any by async, you can't just do a `return` of the data, hence the callbacks.

What you can do is call a third function for both your search functions, which checks if both callbacks were executed. Or nest one call in the other. Then you can safely `console.log` your `videoData`. This would mean breaking your code from it's usual synchronous pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is not one of scope (there is nothing wrong with your scope), but synchronization.  The fact that `searchYTVideos` and `searchVideo` both take a callback indicate to me that they're `asynchronous`; that is, they do their work when the JavaScript engine has time, and *then* the callbacks are invoked.  If you could assign fictional "step numbers", it might look something like this:

```
1   var videoData=[];
2   searchYTVideos("test1",0,function(vidYT){
        //concat to videoData
15      videoData = videoData.concat(vidYT);

    });

3   searchVideo("test2",0,function(vidDM){
        //concat to videoData
23      videoData = videoData.concat(vidDM);
    });
4   console.log(videoData);
    // other stuff happens for a while...
```

Note that in this fictional example, I have `searchYTVideos` finishing first, but there's nothing that says that it couldn't be the other way: that `searchVideo` finishes first, and THEN `searchYTVideos` finishes up.

To solve the problem, you can chain the functions, as others have suggested, or you can use promises:

```
<!-- "Q" promises library -->
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/q.js/1.0.0/q.js"></script>
<script>
    var videoData=[];
    var deferred1 = Q.defer();
    searchYTVideos("test1",0,function(vidYT){
       //concat to videoData
       videoData = videoData.concat(vidYT);
       deferred1.resolve();
    });

    var deferred2 = Q.defer();
    searchVideo("test2",0,function(vidDM){
        //concat to videoData
        videoData = videoData.concat(vidDM);
        deferred2.resolve();
    });

    Q.all([deferred1.promise, deferred2.promise]).then(function(){
        console.log(videoData);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use promise to solve this problem. From [**documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

> The Promise interface represents a proxy for a value not necessarily
>   known at its creation time. It allows you to associate handlers to an
>   asynchronous action's eventual success or failure. This lets
>   asynchronous methods return values like synchronous methods: instead
>   of the final value, the asynchronous method returns a promise of
>   having a value at some point in the future.

Read **[this](https://api.jquery.com/promise/)** and start work. We will use jquery **when** function.

```
$.when(searchYTVideos("test1",0),  searchVideo("test2", 0)).done(function(data){
  // your logic
});
```

My code is just example, promise methodology is very powerful and useful in your case. It helps to avoid spaggeti code.

Also very [good explanation](http://12devs.co.uk/articles/promises-an-alternative-way-to-approach-asynchronous-javascript/) with examples

Comment: Your answer will only work if `searchYTVideos` and `searchVideo` return promises....